# Release Blackberry 10 .bar file to client

Tags: cordova, blackberry, blackberry-10

I have created a signed blackberry app (.bar file) through command line which I have successfully installed in my BB10 device through command line.

But I would like to know how to send this to the client so that it can be installed OTA itself, just for the case of testing?

I don't want to publish it to the app world, isn't there any way other way around where the .bar can be installed easily.?

Any inputs will be highly appreciated

Comment: Maybe stupid idea, but I once loaded over the internet. You only need to be development mode, have IP and password

Comment: @bojan : can you please explain how you did it?I need to release it by 4pm today :(

Comment: Client needs to provide you IP address and password to his device (and be in development mode). Then you go New->BlackBerry Target-> put in IP of that phone and password. Connecting isn't fast, and you have to set up for every device but it works.

Comment: Also look at http://crackberry.com/install-files-ota-blackberry-10 and http://forums.crackberry.com/blackberry-10-os-f269/barinstall-native-app-like-localbar-playbook-845280/

Comment: What about chrome plugin? That is very easy to do

Comment: @bojan:- thanks for the response,I actually downloaded a sideloader tool and documented it and sent it to the client.Hopefully that did the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

You can upload the bar file to your Vendor portal at https://appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/, go through all the steps you would go through before submitting the app (description, images, etc, which can be changed at a later date if you don't have it ready now). Upload the bar file, but don't submit the app for review. This will keep the app in 'draft' format.

From there, the client needs to put their device in developer mode, then open app world, swipe down from the top and go Settings > Development Mode, then enter the Content ID of the app you uploaded to your portal (Found under Manage Products > edit button (pencil) next to your app > ID).

Note: for the app to show up for the client, you have to add their BlackBerry Id email address to your vendor portal under 'Sandbox' in the left hand menu. Also, it will take a couple of hours after you upload the bar to the vendor portal before the client will be able to download it.

This will allow them to install the app, and not have it actually submitted to BlackBerry for review and release. If the client happens to say they want something changed, which requires you to upload the bar file again, you can simply press the edit button, delete your bar file, and upload a new one, without having to fill out all the info again, or increment the version number, since you never actually submitted the app.

Comment: I actually downloaded a sideloader tool and documented it and sent it to the client.